# Battery Holder for 3.7V 3000mAh 18650 Li-ion AAA?

Tags: arduino, batteries

I am interested in using 3.7V 3000mAh 18650 Li-ion AAA batteries (e.g. [EBL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014867612)). However, users indicate  (reading the reviews) that those batteries are not the same size as traditional AAA.

I was going to purchase a standard AAA holder (e.g. [4 X AAA Holder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PZT0A7Y)), but now I am starting to doubt if these batteries will fit the holder.

Does anyone have any experience with 1850 batteries + holders?  I am trying to externally power an Arduino project with them.

Comment: Do you need the AAA size, or 3000mAh capacity? These two parameters are incompatible.

Comment: I just need 3000mAh capacity in 3.7v. I am now looking into converting 12v DC to 3.7v instead. I am not sure I want to worry about 18650 reliability + protection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're much bigger than an AA let alone an AAA battery. Check the dimensions. You can buy 18650 holders (the batteries themselves are actually a bit more difficult to get ahold of from reputable sources).

AAA: 44mm long x 10mm\$\phi\$

18650: 64.8mm long (or longer) x 18.3mm\$\phi\$

There is an additional complication- the 18650s are made with or without protection PCBs which add something like a couple mm to the length.

Comment: I am in need of 3000mAh, do you recommend other types of batteries other than 18650? Do you know of a reputable source for them?

Comment: Protection and safety are issues so the reputable makers don't seem to sell through the usual distributors. Some of the disreputable sources greatly exaggerate the mAh of the stuff they do  offer.

Comment: Also beware at non-trivial current draws of the losses in coil-spring type holder contacts, vs lever spring ones.

Answer (score 2):

18650 is a form factor for batteries, of a certain width and length, nominally 18.6 and 65 mm respectfully. They are not AAA sized, by a long shot. Many places sell 18650 sized battery holders online.

18650 next to a AA.

[image]